# Time complexity for recursive function with random input

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, random, time-complexity

I'm a beginner in C programming so i need some help for my time complexity function.

```
int function(int n)
{ if (n <= 1)
    return n;
int i = random(n-1);
return test(i) + test(n - 1 - i);
}
```

I don't know how to deal with this problem because of the random function which have O(1) complexity which return randomly numbers.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: What again is your question?

Comment: Note that you don't show either `random()` or `test()`, and neither function is defined by the C standard.  That makes it hard to know what they do.  Does `random()` return a random integer between 0 and its argument?  There's no recursion here unless `function()` is called by either `test()` or `random()` — if those do call `function()`, then it is indirect recursion rather than direct recursion.  (Is `test()` a misspelling of `function()`, or `function()` a misspelling of `test()`?  If so, then you have direct recursion once you've fixed the naming.)

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know how to deal with this problem because of the random function which have O(1) complexity which return randomly numbers.

Well clearly you treat the `random(n-1)` call itself as a simple (constant time) call.  Taken in isolation that is straight forward.  The interesting thing is what effect the value returned by the call has on the performance.

- Hint: first consider the best-case and worst-case performance for the algorithm.
- Hint: for the purposes of analysis, consider a  hypothetical version of `random` which generates a number sequence that is the antithesis of random numbers :-)